# Query on mongodb connection

Tags: mongodb

Is there any available mongodb driver that would allow to create connection to database similar to SQL databases and run normal SQL queries?

I would like to create a datasource for the mongodb and then create connection out of it. Also I would want to run normal SQL queries against mongodb. So is there any mongodb driver that comes with a wrapper which would do the conversion for you?

Comment: No, But you can use GUI tool for mongodb like Robomogo

Comment: It will hardly take 2-3 days to go thru all the operation in MongoDB. Wrapper may not help you to understand much about the nosql DB

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB BI connector allows you to connect to MongoDB using the standard SQL connections and allows you to write SQL against your collections. However, I'd advise against it and just to learn some mongo querying itself, it's fairly easy to learn and they're even comparisons between SQL and mongo query (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)

BI Connector - https://www.mongodb.com/products/bi-connector

There are more ODBC drivers out there for MongoDB just give it quick google, most of them allow you to trial their connector.

Comment: We offer one such ODBC Driver for MongoDB: https://www.progress.com/odbc/mongodb  (This is Certified by MongoDB)